# Getting started with Faker.js with Meteorite

Tags: javascript, meteor, faker

I am trying to user Faker.js with Meteorite. I have added this package:

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/Faker.js

I am trying to add fake users on server startup:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup

    // add 100 fake tips and 10 fake articles and 50 fake users
    for (var i=0; i<50; i++) {
        // Accounts.createUser(Faker.Internet.userName(), Faker.Internet.email(), "1234");
    }

});
```

but I get an error:

> ReferenceError: Faker is not defined

Not sure how to fix this...

Comment: Until Faker is ready, you can use [Fake](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/fake).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend installing the `npm` package, and adding Faker as an NPM module. It's quite simple:

1. `mrt add npm`
2. Create a `packages.json` file in your project root, and add `{ "Faker": "0.5.11" }`
3. `mrt update`
4. Use Faker in your code by doing `Faker = Meteor.require('Faker');`

Now you can use it like normal, e.g. `Faker.Internet.email()`

Answer (score 3):

The author of Faker.js on atmosphere needs to update the package for it to work properly on Meteor 0.6.5.

In meteor 0.6.5 packages need to explicitly expose their variables. This was done so that packages variables don't conflict.

For the 'fakerjs' package the edits look pretty minor because it just interfaces the npm module.

You need to export 'Faker' in the `package.on_use` method in the [package.js](https://github.com/digilord/meteor-faker/blob/master/package.js) with an `api.export`, if you contact the author or send him a push request you could push it through faster. More details on how to expose the variables can be found in the [namespacing section](http://docs.meteor.com/#namespacing) on the meteor docs.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not entirely sure how this all works -- I tried adding `api.export("Faker")` to the `package.on_use` method. That seemed to get rid of the error but now I get: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Lorem' of undefined`. Reading around online, I found this may be because I'm on the server and I should add `var Faker = Npm.require('Faker');`, but then I get a different error: `Error: Cannot find module 'Faker'`. Thanks for the help